# What is/are the word(s) for the overwhelming feeling of relief?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am describing in a college app essay the feeling I felt when I finally did not experience overwhelming anxiety when presenting in front of the class. I have only felt this way when presenting topics surrounding math and science.

I need a word that encapsulates the feeling of utter relief. One example of this could be when someone finds out their loved one is not going to die. The cold, unrelenting grip of worry is released from the shoulders and lungs and that overwhelming sense of relief is felt. The lightness of the shoulders. The newfound ease of breath. What is a good word that encapsulates this?

Comment: Not a one-word option, but "utter relief" expresses the idea well.

Comment: Not everything can be described by one word in English.  Reductio ad absurdum:  What is one word that encapsulates the novel War and Peace?  Utter relief cannot be improved upon in your context.

Comment: I would suggest adding emphasis on the word relief.

Answer (score -1):

The complete lack of anxiety is captured by the words *ease* and *serenity*. You feel at ease; you feel serene.

> Serenity =
>
> the quality of being peaceful and calm
>
> Ease =
>
> the state of experiencing no difficulty, effort, pain, etc.
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ease?q=Ease)